# Redirection not working in include file

Tags: php

```
<?php
if (!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP']))   //check ip from share internet
    {
      $ipaddress = $_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP']."\r\n";
    }
elseif (!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR']))   //to check if ip is pass from proxy
    {
      $ipaddress = $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR']."\r\n";
    }
else
    {
      $ipaddress = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']."\r\n";
    }
$savedips = "adderss.txt";
$lines = file($savedips);
foreach($lines as $line_num => $line)
    {
if($line==$ipaddress)
    {
exit;
    }
    }

fclose($file);

$file = 'adderss.txt';  //this is the file to which the IP address will be written; name it your way.
$fp = fopen($file, 'a');
fwrite($fp, $ipaddress);
fclose($fp);
header("Location: http://www.google.com");
?>
```

Hello all. I included the above code into a php file everything works great but the redirection part is not working. Can some one tell me how to fix that issue?

Comment: If the IP address is present in the file, script ends with `exit;`, not with redirection... Otherwise there is no reason why the redirection should not work.

Comment: You could probably do something with the indention of that code to make it more readable. That being said, is there any errors in your logs (if not, did you enable error-reporting?)

Comment: `fclose($file);` generates an error which if displayed will cause the redirect not to happen.

Comment: [13-Feb-2017 21:38:52 UTC] PHP Warning:  fclose() expects parameter 1 to be resource, null given in /home/tips/public_html/verify.php on line 24
[13-Feb-2017 21:38:57 UTC] PHP Warning:  Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /home/tips/public_html/wp-includes/formatting.php:4971) in /home/tips/public_html/verify.php on line 31 Here is the error that I can see in error logs.

Comment: But if ip address is not there is should redirect but its not.

Comment: `exit;` ends the script execution completely. Use `break;` to break out of the iteration. Your code will always add the IP to the file, though.